# How to connect with Oracle 11g Express addition?

Tags: visual-studio, oracle11g

I have downloaded and installed ORACLE 11g express edition. And have created workspace in it, Now i want to connect with this Oracle data base from Visual studio in c# or JAVA. Can any one please tell me how to accomplish this step by step. i would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

have a look on the link for Connecting To Oracle XE Using C# 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20322/Simple-Introduction-to-Oracle-XE-with-C